# Open battery popup from C#

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I want to display the battery popup when the user clicks on the tray icon of my application.
I searched around for quite a while but I couldn't find any API for this, neither .NET nor native. Is this possible (e.g. via P/Invoke)? I am using WinForms, but that shouldn't be relevant.

I am speaking of these windows:
[image]
[image]

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: I think the question is clear: "Is there an API to do this?". Effort: "*I searched around but I couldn't find any API for this*" (is OP expected to list all of the search terms which didn't bring up anything?). WPF/UWP: it doesn't matter - OP is after an API they can invoke to do this, which is unlikely to be WPF or UWP-specific.

Comment: @canton7 I second that! Not every question that doesn't include code means that it's too broad. OP is not asking for a full example either.

Comment: I don't think there's an API, but you should be able to use Windows UI Automation: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=43863

Comment: @SimonMourier good shout! Confirmed that this is possible, but it relies on picking out the (localized) text associated with the icon, which might be e.g. "Fully charged (100%)"

Comment: @canton7 Having to rely on localized text unfortunately makes things exponentially more difficult

Comment: Agreed. But "It's possible but undesirable" is a step forward from "It's impossible"

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Windows UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) as explained here: [Enumerating notification icons via UI Automation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=43863)

The difficulty is to find the power icon, whatever the end-user language is. Luckily, some icons have an [AutomationId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/use-the-automationid-property) set, so we can search the power one using its id.

There is one issue though: for some reason the UI automation dlls (UIAutomationXXX) shipped with Windows are not up to date (and buggy) so don't use them for this task, and use the `UIAComWrapper` dll (originally written by a Microsoft guy) instead, for example from here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/UIAComWrapper/

So, here is a sample Console app code (with helper code from the link above):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // you can find the value of this guid using SDK's "inspect" tool, hovering over the power icon.
    var SCAID_Power = new Guid("7820ae75-23e3-4229-82c1-e41cb67d5b9c");
    var power = EnumNotificationIcons().FirstOrDefault(i => string.Compare(i.Current.AutomationId, SCAID_Power.ToString("B"), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0);
    if (power != null)
    {
        power.InvokeButton();
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<AutomationElement> EnumNotificationIcons()
{
    var userArea = AutomationElement.RootElement.Find("User Promoted Notification Area");
    if (userArea != null)
    {
        foreach (var button in userArea.EnumChildButtons())
        {
            yield return button;
        }

        foreach (var button in userArea.GetTopLevelElement().Find("System Promoted Notification Area").EnumChildButtons())
        {
            yield return button;
        }
    }

    var chevron = AutomationElement.RootElement.Find("Notification Chevron");
    if (chevron != null && chevron.InvokeButton())
    {
        foreach (var button in AutomationElement.RootElement.Find("Overflow Notification Area").EnumChildButtons())
        {
            yield return button;
        }
    }
}

public static class AutomationHelpers
{
    public static AutomationElement Find(this AutomationElement root, string name) => root.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, name));
    public static IEnumerable<AutomationElement> EnumChildButtons(this AutomationElement parent) => parent == null ? Enumerable.Empty<AutomationElement>() : parent.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Button)).Cast<AutomationElement>();

    static public AutomationElement GetTopLevelElement(this AutomationElement element)
    {
        AutomationElement parent;
        while ((parent = TreeWalker.ControlViewWalker.GetParent(element)) != AutomationElement.RootElement)
        {
            element = parent;
        }
        return element;
    }

    public static bool InvokeButton(this AutomationElement button)
    {
        var invokePattern = button.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern;
        invokePattern?.Invoke();
        return invokePattern != null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good tip with with UIAComWrapper - I wasn't able to find an AutomationId for the power icon when I was playing around, and that's probably why. Perhaps worth mentioning that this might not work on future versions of Windows (with the chevron, etc)?

Comment: @canton7 - well, tell that to Raymond :-)

Comment: Raymond told me? The article you linked goes to great lengths talking about the changes to the code needed for different versions of Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Your app should be able to use the same information that the OS uses to display the battery stats. This doesn't mean you should use the same UI as the OS. I don't suppose you can access that programmatically. And if you did, how would you be able to plug it into your application?...

Try querying WMI to get the data you want. Perhaps class `Win32_Battery` is what you need.

Comment: That is not the point. I am already getting the data and using it in a differrent place. I want to display the *native* popup on click, not a rebuilt version of it.